# app.config assemblies

Tags: assemblies, app-config

I have the following in my app.config.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
         <sectionGroup name="FooGroup">
              <section
                  name="Foo"
                  type="Bar.FooSection"
                  allowLocation="true"
                  allowDefinition="Everywhere"
          />
          </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 ....
```

Bar.FooSection is in another assembly however, so I get a TypeLoadException.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tentative guess would be that you need to specify the assembly as a part of the type attribute's value, ie. **make the mentioned `type` [fully qualified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx)**, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass, MyAssembly,
Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089
```

(Example [taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx).)

You can probably omit the `Version`, `Culture`, and `PublicKeyToken`, and just write:

```
... type="Foobar.FooSection, FooAssembly" ...
```

Comment: using typeof(TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass).AssemblyQualifiedName get's you all you need. Thank's stakx!